# @import not working on my site

Tags: css, import

Instead of listing multiple CSS stylesheets in an HTML5 document, you can instead do it this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/global.css">
```

where the above code is at the top of the HTML right after the charset line and global.css contains the following (nothing else):

```
@import url(normalize.css);
@import url(ccsda.css);
@import url(print.css);
```

But when I do that browsers don't recognize my CSS, which works fine when listing the stylesheets separately. I've tried it with and without quotation marks around the stylesheet names in the @import command. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: put double quote before & the end of file name @import url("normalize.css"); or just import "normalize.css";

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import

Comment: I have tried both of these, still not working. Ideas? Do I need something in the global.css before the @import commands? Charset, maybe?

Comment: One pitfall can be "These rules must precede all other types of rules, except @charset rules;" thanks to wf4

Comment: Thanks, Setyl, I'll look into it, even though this is an old request (2014).

Answer (score 0):

Put the url in quotes:

```
@import url("normalize.css");
@import url("ccsda.css");
@import url("print.css");
```

or

```
@import "normalize.css";
@import "ccsda.css";
@import "print.css";
```

Comment: I tried it with quotes, but it made no difference. Any ideas?